# Improve the community wiki tooltip

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface

> Community owned posts do not generate any reputation for the owner, have a lower reputation barrier for collaborative editing, and show only a revision history instead of a signature block.

It is [agreed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) that the main point of CW is editing, not avoiding reputation generation. The tooltip needs to set its priorities straight then!

Proposed rephrased replacement:

> Mark an answer Community wiki to encourage users to edit it. The reputation barrier for editing will be lowered for this post; however, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone.

Comment: +1, but why not "Mark a post..." in general? And maybe include "Answers to CW questions are also CW"

Comment: @Tobias, [questions are no longer allowed to start as CW](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192).

Comment: that's new. Ok, nuff said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changed to

> Marking an answer community wiki encourages others to edit it by lowering the reputation barrier required to edit. However, you will not gain any upvote reputation from it. This cannot be undone.