# Moderator's "Convert to wiki" yielding an exception on this money.SE question

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-wiki, moderator-abilities

I'm a moderator at money.SE, and I'm trying to convert the following question to a community wiki:

[In Ireland & want to buy stock online. What cheap discount stock brokers offer online trading for the EU?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4258/in-ireland-want-to-buy-stock-online-what-cheap-discount-stock-brokers-offer-on)

However, the system is reporting in a yellow box (orange on SO, pictured. -BtL):

[image: An exception occurred during conversion to wiki]

Tried a few times, no luck, same error each time.

Comment: +1. Cannot [CW-ize a question in math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7864/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics) either.

Comment: Seeing the same thing on SO.

Comment: Yeah, looks like the only way to do it right now is to edit and check the wiki box. But then you have to do it for all the answers individually.

Comment: @mmyers: D'oh!  Forgot about the old school method.  Thanks.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was my bad; sorry for the bug.

A fix will be pushed in tonight's deployment.

Answer (score 1):

[What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Reading that, though, I'm led to believe **moderators** should *still* be able to convert something to CW (see Aarobot's comment).  I'm a moderator at money.SE, but I can't convert to CW.

Comment: Oh, whoops. I didn't see that part. This is likely the cause of the error, though, so it may be a bug since this is a fairly recent change.

Comment: It's not the cause of the error.  Mod-convert-to-CW was working for a long time after that change.  This is a new bug.