# Allow people to make their own questions Community WIki at 3k rep

Tags: discussion, feature-request, community-wiki

I **completely** agree that I shouldn't be able to make other people's questions CW. But I do think that I should be able to make my own question CW. I can't see a moderator inflecting penalties on somebody for making their own question CW when it shouldn't have been. Although the mods may be quick, the can never be as quick as me doing it myself. I've had questions that got several votes and went over an hour before being made CW.

EDIT: Whoops, I thought 10k users had this privilege. Turns out its only the mods. Apparently we're supposed to flag posts ourselves to be made CW. This seems like the most unintuitive and wrongly buried  'feature' of Stackoverflow right now.

Comment: I've read somewhere that it becomes community wiki anyway if you edit it often enough. (I'm always wary about *that* threshold. I think it's 10 revisions. I'd vote against lowering that.)

Comment: @mario "Community Wiki is triggered after the 10th OP revision excluding the original posting", this was the conclusion that was established by a couple people by accident a couple months ago (the post is deleted, however). Beyond that, 5 people editing a post also converts it to Community Wiki, as does getting at least 30 live answers to one question.

Comment: It's funny, I saw the title and came to downvote and then realized that I already had before you edited. In response to the edit, I personally don't think it's buried deeply enough and and don't really understand the purpose of allowing people to add new CWis to begin with. They're really nto a very good feature that were heavily abused. They have a noble goal but a poor implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Please see the answer to [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192) for the background on why this feature was removed.

The bottom line is, if you think your question needs to be Community Wiki, then it's probably not an appropriate question to be asking in the first place.  Either it's asking for verifiable information or it's not; if it is, then answerers deserve the rep, and if it's not, well then it's not a constructive question.

That's why nobody has this privilege anymore.  Mods can still do it, but they would only do it to correct an immediate problem (i.e. a flood of votes going to an obvious rep-farming question).

You are **not** supposed to flag your own questions to be made Community Wiki by the mods.  Instead, you should ask good questions and not start polls.  At this point, on *most* SE sites, mods will or should be ignoring "should be CW" moderator flags.

Comment: How to disassociate question from account?