# How many times can one edit one's own post?

Tags: support, edits

I usually don't need to edit my posts more than five times (at least, I haven't done so so far).

I am just worried, is there any limit to the number of edits allowed? (Apart from the *I am a human* testing, is there any objection from Stack Exchange's side?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any limits on the number of times authors can edit their posts.

However, if you edit your post 10 times it will be switched over to community wiki mode. You can see all of the implications of that in [this answer to "What are 'Community Wiki' posts?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

In a comment, [Grace Note](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/146126/grace-note) provided some additional references:

> For exact limits, see the comments on [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/allow-people-to-make-their-own-questions-community-wiki-at-3k-rep). For which kinds of
>   edits actually affect it, see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode/62673#62673). – Grace Note

Comment: uhm, are you sure? I believe I've edited far more than 10 time without switching to CW.

Comment: @aloobe I know there is a number of edits that will switch an answer to community wiki as I encountered it once myself. (Also, in addition to the FAQ, there are some [other questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/so-is-too-eager-to-turn-my-edited-answers-into-community-wiki) on that topic.) On the other hand, I am only mostly (not entirely) certain that the number is 10. Although on that point, it seems useful to note that edits close together in time do not count separately.

Comment: @aioobe Rollbacks aren't counted I believe, and multiple edits done within 5 minutes of each other by the same user is considered as a single edit. The 10 edit "limit" is definitely there and real though.

Comment: ok. then it's the 5 minutes thingy that I've run into when editing my posts.

Comment: For exact limits, see the comments on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70365/allow-people-to-make-their-own-questions-community-wiki-at-3k-rep). For which kinds of edits actually affect it, see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60923/which-edit-actions-can-move-a-post-into-community-wiki-mode/62673#62673).

Comment: @Grace, I am sorry but exact limits (in number) isn't available in the link, but I thank you for a live example mentioned there :) regards.

Comment: @infant It's "10 edits by the author excluding the original posting". There are two separate links, only the first one mentions all of the specific numbers, in the comment by myself.

Comment: @Grace, ohk .. got it, thanks :) btw, you could have posted it as answer :) regards.

Comment: @aioobe, @moberley, your discussion blossoms useful info :) accepted as BA, thanks-regards:infant pro :)