# Misleading sentence in blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, wording

The new [Putting the Community back in Wiki](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) blog post contains this sentence:

> An author can still apply the status manually when posting or when editing their own post

This is true for answers, but for three and half years ordinary users [can't mark their own question as Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67192/152859) anymore. Can the sentence be changed please, to something like:

> An author can still apply the status manually when posting or when editing their own answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've revised the sentence as specified. Enjoy! ♪