# Marking a Question Community Wiki

Tags: support, questions, community-wiki

How do I mark a question as a community wiki? I know how to mark a answer as a community wiki, but I couldn't figure out how to mark a question as one. I don't see the little check.

Comment: [What can we do to make Community Wiki better?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better) has your answer: you can't.

Comment: There's a [whole FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/226203) about Community Wiki, and [the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/226203) there has a section on "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really think a question should be community wiki, flag a mod with "other" and explain why.