# Can anyone explain these cases (increase/decrease) in community wiki questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, trends

I am looking at the number of community wiki questions and answers over time. Making a question community wiki automatically transforms all of its answers to community wiki also. Thus, I remove those answers from the analysis (for the answer figure) whose parent questions are also community wiki. Interestingly, I find sharp drops in questions after July 2010 and after March 2014. After some investigation, I find that in April 2014, all automatic triggers for community wiki were stopped. While this explains the drop-2 in wiki questions but I could not find any reason for drop-1. Similarly, I also observe some interesting cases for wiki answers (see drop-1, drop-2 and a sudden increase in wiki answers). Can anyone shed light (possible explanation) on these cases?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we disable automatic community wiki conversion for answer edits?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203616/can-we-disable-automatic-community-wiki-conversion-for-answer-edits)

Comment: @DavidPostill Not a duplicate. That post doesn't explain the earlier massive drops neither does it explain the later sudden increase.

Comment: To answer part of your question: in 2010 it became [no longer possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67192/377214) for question authors to mark their own questions as community wiki.

Comment: @Sonic the Introverted Hedgehog. Thanks for the information. Do you know when wiki features for answers introduce or change? Is there any way to find feature addition or deletion in SE? That can possibly explain drops in answers.

Comment: The community maintains a changelog at [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange?r=SearchResults&s=1|336.2424).